# How to add a column using sql that in every record the unit is the result of computation of other columns?

Tags: sql, insert, netezza

I am using Netezza to manipulate some data. I am trying to add a column to a table with values that are results of computation of other columns.

First of all, I ran this sql to create a table to rearrange the order of other table:

```
CREATE TABLE SEQ_6_3_FNN_CID218_ORDERED AS
SELECT A.* FROM SEQ_6_3_FNN_CID218 A
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP
```

And then, what I need is like this, assuming columns TMP and ATT1 already there, and I need to insert ATT2:

```
TMP ATT1 ATT2
1    1   NULL
2    4   4-1=3
3    5   5-4=1
4    8   8-5=3
5    9   9-8=1
6    12  12-9=3
```

What is the sql that can achieve this? Or is there a way that this can be achieved directly running sql on SEQ_6_3_FNN_CID218 without running my create new table by order?

Thanks very much for your help.
HELP STILL NEEDED!

Comment: @OverMind -- it's possible to subtract negative numbers

Comment: What flavor? SQL Server?

Comment: @OverMind Just insert whatever is computed, assuming TMP is of type TIMESTAMP, and is the key, and ATT1 and ATT2 are NUMERIC.

Comment: @roryap Yes, sql server.

Comment: @roryap I am new, do not know much the diff btw sql and sql server. :D

Comment: Google SQL vs. SQL Server.

Comment: "*I am using Netezza*" - Netezza is not SQL Server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name NO. It is nzsql. But it is compatible with sql.

Comment: SQL is just a (standardized) **query** language. The term SQL does **not** refer to any specific DBMS product. Every relational DBMS uses "SQL" as its query language - and each one has its own dialect that deviates from the standard.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for here is often referred to as a "calculated column". Netezza does not implement this feature, nor does it implement triggers (another method by which you might achieve the same result).  Since Netezza is focused on data warehousing, the sorts of calculations you're talking about are usually done in the ETL process, by the ETL tool.

The good news is that you can do this purely through SQL with the LAG function, which is designed to do exactly this. Then, if you like, you can encode that in a view.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> insert into base_table select * from base_ext;
INSERT 0 6
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from base_table order by col1;
 COL1 | COL2
------+------
    1 |    1
    2 |    4
    3 |    5
    4 |    8
    5 |    9
    6 |   12
(6 rows)

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select col1, col2, col2 - lag(col2,1,NULL) over (
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)(> order by col1 asc) col3 from base_table;
 COL1 | COL2 | COL3
------+------+------
    1 |    1 |
    2 |    4 |    3
    3 |    5 |    1
    4 |    8 |    3
    5 |    9 |    1
    6 |   12 |    3
(6 rows)
```

For clarity, the SQL again is:

```
select col1, col2, col2 - lag(col2,1,NULL) over ( order by col1 asc) col3 from base_table;
```

Comment: Thx very much, this is indeed helpful! What does "lag" mean here?

Comment: Lag refers to referencing the previous row, which "lags" behind the current row by an offset amount ( in this case by 1). For "previous row" to make sense you have to have an order defined, and here we are specifying that COL1 defines that ordering.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What does the 3rd parameter of lag, "NULL", and I guess the 2nd parameter "1" means "lag 1"? :)

Comment: The second parameter is the offset, or how many rows to count back. For your example we wanted to look at the row 1 row back from the current row, so the offset would be 1. The third parameter is a scalar value that should be returned when the offset would reference a row that doesn't exist. In your example there is no row before the first row for the reference and calculation to work on, so we set it to return NULL.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server can't do this "natively", but you could accomplish this with an insert and update trigger that responds to changes to the two columns and updates the third column.

Edit --  I stand corrected: SQL Server *can* do this natively.  See Amirreza Keshavarz's answer.

Comment: Can you make a small example? I am new to sql. Thx!

Comment: It is not what I want. Although I am new, but not so stupid. His answer is far from the correct one. I wish to unvote that if I have reputation 125..

Answer (score 0):

```
Alter table SEQ_6_3_FNN_CID218_ORDERED
Add att2 as (att1-tmp)
```

Comment: I am sorry, but it is not just att1-tmp. It is att1(current)-att1(previous)